# Bitcoin wallet to be integrated into a Webapp

Tags: wallet, webapp

Does anyone know if exist a Bitcoin wallet that allows to be integrated into a Webapp? I mean a kind of Metamask for Bitcoin. What I should do is develop a Dapp that allows the user to send txs from it without implementing the key management part.

Comment: you can use the RPC framework of Bitcoin core

Comment: however in that case the user should insert its rpc credentials into the webpage right?

Comment: No, the node bitcoin work with your server, you must create the system of the user manager. With bitcoin core is possible to create your architecture, also I think not to exist anything software (beautiful and done). ps: look on github. If you are new to Bitcoin, I think you must know the technology, after this, you can choose the better solution for you.

Comment: no i would like to don't use any server! only a front end connected in localhost with bitcoin core! but i read that is not a good solution!